# Power Automate - Action 'Get_tables' failed

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, error, power-automate, flow

Why am I getting error Action 'Get_tables' failed?

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "The resource could not be found.\r\nclientRequestId: 58bfb995-21d7-4fda-af12-6f61e663b189\r\nserviceRequestId: 6bee2833-510e-4646-a9d4-e6a54a277ad2",
  "error": {
    "message": "The resource could not be found."
  },
  "source": "excelonline-eus.azconn-eus-002.p.azurewebsites.net"
}


The resource could not be found.
clientRequestId: 58bfb995-21d7-4fda-af12-6f61e663b189
serviceRequestId: 6bee2833-510e-4646-a9d4-e6a54a277ad2
```

the file does exist in the location. Any reason as to why this is happening?

Error:

[image]

full flow -

[image]
[image]

Comment: Quick question - Is user running the Power automate flow has access to the excel file? Make sure user has at least read access to the excel file.

Comment: Are you selecting excel file in Get tables action manually or using any variable/dynamic content for site URL, document library or file name/identifier?

Comment: Yes the user has access to the excel file. I believe using the file picker to select the .xlsb file. But also note this file is refreshed daily.

Comment: Are you deleting the file and creating new one daily or replacing the existing file? File name is exact same everyday (case sensitive)? Also, check if the file is checked out or goes in draft mode after adding to library every day.

Comment: The file is deleted and recreated daily (using a separate flow). File name will remain the same always. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Maybe file identifier is changing every time file is deleted. Instead of directly selecting file from file picker, set a file name in one variable at the start of the flow and use it to pass to get tables action. Let me know If it works, I will also try to Replicate the same at my end.

Comment: What is the trigger used for your flow, scheduled/manual/automatic? Are you sure excel file is present in library while flow run starts?

Comment: Trigger is recurrance or I manually run. Yes the file is present in the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are deleting excel file and recreating it daily, there might be issue related to file identifier when you are selecting file from file picker in "Get tables" action.

Instead of above approach, set a file name in one variable at the start of the flow and use it to pass to "File" input of get tables action as shown below:

[image]

Pass file name variable to "File" input using **Dynamic content**:

[image]

I did few tests from my end and flow worked for me when file is deleted and re-uploaded to the SharePoint document library.

Comment: still getting error - ive included he full flow.. sigh.

Comment: Is issue related to `Get Tables` action solved? I think you are getting error in different action (`List rows present in a table`) now. Did you try using same excel variable name in this action as well?

Comment: I believe its working - just testing it out! i havnt forgotten!

Comment: Thanks Ganesh it seems to be working! But it takes so long... like 6 hours...I wonder if there is a way to make this faster..

Comment: Great, glad it is working for you! It maybe slower based on how many tables and rows you have in each table. You can try enabling "concurrency control" settings for apply to each actions and see if it makes any difference, check: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understand-concurrency-control-in-apply-to-each-loop-in-power-automate/. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: ill create a new question for this issue, ill mark this as complete.

Comment: Sure, thank you!